# Protractor test chrome doesn't click on item while safari does

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor

My test passes without problems in safari while in chrome this particular bit doesn't seem to work:

```
 it('should click the first source and get to the source preview page', function () {
    var grid_icon = element(by.css('.fa-th'));
    var sources = element.all(by.repeater('source in shownSources'));

    sources.get(0).element(by.tagName('a')).click();
    browser.pause();
    // Check url
    expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toContain('/source/');
});
```

After clicking on the hyperlink it should change to a url containing "/source/". This works perfectly fine in Safari but in Chrome it fails

My protractor config file:

```
exports.config = {
framework: 'jasmine2',
seleniumServerJar: '../node_modules/protractor/selenium/selenium-server-standalone-2.45.0.jar',
seleniumPort: 4444,
troubleshoot: false,
basePath: '../',
specs: ['protractor/***/**/*.js'],
baseUrl: 'http://localhost:9000',
capabilities: {
    browserName: 'chrome'
},
onPrepare: function() {
    browser.manage().window().maximize();
}
};
```

Edit: My initial problem seems to not occur anymore. But the test still behaves very strange. This bit here works perfectly fine in Safari:

```
it('should add all sources to the list and show the cart icon on the source in inventory', function () {
    browser.get('/sources');
    var ordersources = element.all(by.repeater('orderSource in orderSources'));
    var sources = element.all(by.repeater('source in shownSources'));

    sources.get(0).element(by.css('a')).click();
    var add_to_cart_btn = element(by.binding('addBtnText'));
    add_to_cart_btn.click();
    browser.get('/sources');

    sources.get(1).element(by.css('a')).click();
    var add_to_cart_btn = element(by.binding('addBtnText'));
    add_to_cart_btn.click();
    browser.get('/sources');

    browser.pause();

    sources.get(2).element(by.css('a')).click();
    var add_to_cart_btn = element(by.binding('addBtnText'));
    add_to_cart_btn.click();
    browser.get('/sources');

    expect(ordersources.count()).toBe(3);

    sources.each(function (field) {
        var isInCart_symbol = field.element(by.css('.fa-cart-arrow-down'));
        expect(isInCart_symbol.getAttribute('aria-hidden')).toBe('false');
    });
});
```

In Chrome however the 'a' item isn't found the second time and the browser.sleep() is never executed and the next 'it' begins to run.

EDIT: I got it to work by using a another html element by the class attribute.

```
element.(by.css('.example'))
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assumming that when you say it fails, the expect is failing? Here are 3 possible things you could try.

```
// Wait Till Url Contains
function WaitTillUrlContains(text, time, errMessage){
  if(typeof(time) ==='undefined') time = 5000;
  browser.getCurrentUrl().then(function (currentUrl) {
    browser.wait(function () {
       return browser.getCurrentUrl().then(function (newUrl) {
          var test = newUrl;
          if( test.indexOf(text) >= 0){
            // Found word
            return true;
          }

       });
    }, time , errMessage);
  });
};
```

(1) add a wait before the expect.

```
it('should click the first source and get to the source preview page', function () {
    var grid_icon = element(by.css('.fa-th'));
    var sources = element.all(by.repeater('source in shownSources'));

    sources.get(0).element(by.tagName('a')).click();

    // Check url
    WaitTillUrlContains("/source/", 5000, "✗ Failed to wait for page to load");
    expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toContain('/source/');
});
```

(2) do a .then() function after the click

```
it('should click the first source and get to the source preview page', function () {
    var grid_icon = element(by.css('.fa-th'));
    var sources = element.all(by.repeater('source in shownSources'));

    sources.get(0).element(by.tagName('a')).click().then(function(){

        // Check url
        WaitTillUrlContains("/source/", 5000, "✗ Failed to wait for page to load");
        expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toContain('/source/');
    });
});
```

(3) do a .then() function after getting the element then do the click

```
it('should click the first source and get to the source preview page', function () {
    var grid_icon = element(by.css('.fa-th'));
    var sources = element.all(by.repeater('source in shownSources'));

    sources.get(0).element(by.tagName('a')).then(function(elem){

        elem.click();
        // Check url
        WaitTillUrlContains("/source/", 5000, "✗ Failed to wait for page to load");
        expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toContain('/source/');
    });
});
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't sepcify enough.The problem I mentioned I mentioned in my question doesn't occur anymore. But the test still behaves very strangely.

Comment: Sorry I didn't specifiy my problem. Please see my edit

Answer (score 1):

The reason why your link isn't found the second time is because you reload the page with `browser.get()`. After the reload, the `sources` handle is lost and webdriver doesn't know what element to operate on.

You either need to declare `sources` variable again after the page reload or avoid reloading the page.